# Project using git with MonoDevelop / Windows 7

Tags: git, mono, monodevelop

I have created a project on Visual Web Developer Express 2010 and added it to github.

https://github.com/vmrocha/jQueryLab

When I try to build it on MonoDevelop or open the "Version Control" menu I get the following error:

```
   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NGit.Util.FS' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Sharpen.FilePath..ctor(String other, String child)
   at NGit.Util.FS.SearchPath(String path, String[] lookFor)
   at NGit.Util.FS_Win32_Cygwin.IsCygwin()
   at NGit.Util.FS.Detect(Nullable`1 cygwinUsed)
   at NGit.Util.FS.Detect()
   at NGit.Util.FS..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.SetupWorkTree()
   at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.Setup()
   at NGit.Storage.File.FileRepository..ctor(FilePath gitDir)
   at NGit.Storage.File.FileRepository..ctor(String gitDir)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.LocalGitRepository..ctor(String path)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitRepository..ctor(FilePath path, String url)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitVersionControl.GetRepositoryReference(FilePath path, String id)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepositoryReference(String path, String id)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepository(IWorkspaceObject entry)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.SolutionVersionControlCommandHalder.GetItems()
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.SolutionVersionControlCommandHalder.Update(CommandInfo info)
   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.InternalUpdate(CommandInfo info)
   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DefaultUpdateCommandInfo(ActionCommand cmd, CommandInfo info)
   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommandInfo(Object commandId, CommandTargetRoute targetRoute)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what can happen if your MonoDevelop project is in a Git repository. Windows+Git+MonoDevelop is a lethal combination. To fix this, go into MonoDevelop -> Tools -> Add-in Manager -> Version Control - and then disable Git support.

Comment: I was experiencing the same thing in Unity + MonoDevelop. These steps resolved my issue. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something wrong in your source path `Illegal characters in path` for 'NGit.Util.FS' for MonoDevelop

Try to move source to the another folder (for test reason let it be C:\Temp) and try to open project again